# Is there any event before source is updated in binding in WPF?

Tags: wpf, binding

I am looking for something that fire before the source is update

So instead of

```
Binding.SourceUpdated
```

I want

```
Binding.PreviewSourceUpdated
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you would need to handle this on your UI element and intercept the event if it's not ideal.  So for example say you had a text box and a user pressed a key.  You would use the PreviewTextInput (or similar preview) to see if you wanted the data changed - then mark the event has handled if you didn't.

The only other option that I know of is to use DataValidation and not allow the property to be updated for the model side.